# insertar caracteres en una string si los cuatro caracteres anteriores son un número

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Tengo un string en la que cada vez que hay un número no hay un espacio. Me gustaría crearlo y añadir una coma.

Por ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
2013 Presidential2008 Presidential2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun
```

Se convertiría en:

```
2013 Presidential, 2008 Presidential, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun
```

Por el momento tengo:

```
for char in s:
...     if char.isalpha():
            ???
```

Intenté también con javascript:

```
function isNumber(i) {
    return (i >= '0' && i <= '9');
}
for (var x = 0; x < text.length; x++)
{
    var c = text.charAt(x);
    if isNumber(i){
        // add a ", " before and move to the next char which is a letter
        text[:x] + ', ' + text[x:]
    }   
}
```

Pero me devuelve `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añado una nueva solución insertando una coma y un espacio entre el grupo 1 (No dígitos) y el grupo 2 (dígitos):

```
import re

cadena = "2013 Presidential2008 Presidential2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun"
print(re.sub(r'(\D)(\d)', r'\1, \2', cadena))
```

Salida:

```
2013 Presidential, 2008 Presidential, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares, las cuales sirven para encontrar patrones en cadenas de texto, en este caso buscaría números en tu cadena que se encuentren posterior a una letra(si solo se intenta buscar números y la cadena ya esta bien escrita volverá a añadir el espacio y la coma), para despues usar `replace` y reemplazarla.

```
import re

cadena = "2013 Presidential2008 Presidential2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun"
coincidencias = set(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z][0-9]+", cadena))

for i in coincidencias:
    cadena = cadena.replace(i, f", {i[1:]}")

print(cadena)
```

**Salida**

> 2013 Presidentia, 2008 Presidentia, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runof, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun

**Explicacion**

El comando findall regresa una lista con todas las coincidencias encontradas en una cadena, dada un expresion regular, que en este ejemplo fue `[a-zA-Z][0-9]+` ,esta expresión lo que hace es encontrar las cadenas que tengan una letra ya sea minúscula o mayuscula `[a-zA-Z]` y le prosiga alguno o mas dígitos `[0-9]+` (para eso es el mas en la expresion regular), ya solo queda iterar sobre las coincidencias y remplazar, omitiendo el primer caracter que es la letra.

Comment: Esta solución es erronea y probablemente el OP no se ha dado cuenta. La salida elimina un caracter (Presidential >> Presidentia, Runoff >>Runof)

Answer (score 1):

1. Lo que hace es básicamente, comprobar donde estan los numeros en el
   string y guardarlos en una lista.
2. Despues elimina de esa los repetidos, para evitar que al
   reemplazarlo en el string original añada comas y espacios de mas.
3. Reemplaza en el string original los numeros, por el mismo numero
   incluyendo una coma y un espacio
4. Y por ultimo comprueba los dos primeros dígitos, para que en caso de
   que el string comenzara por un numero no incluya una coma y espacio
   al principio del string.

```
import re

string = "2013 Presidential2008 Presidential2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun"

matches = re.findall("(\d+)", string)

matches = list(dict.fromkeys(matches))

for num in matches:
    string=string.replace(num, ', '+num)

if  string[0]+string[1]==', ':
    string=string[2:]

print(string)
```

No lo tomes como la mejor manera de hacerlo, sino como una guia de donde obtener mejores ideas